# Using Xamarin Forms 3 FlowDirection can we present Master-Details View from right to left

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a Xamarin Forms application for Android and iOS. Is it possible to use the new FlowDirection property introduced in Xamarin.Forms 3.0 to make the master details view from right to left including the menu which is presented from left as opposed to be from right in RTL languages?
I tried setting the MasterDetail page property but still the menu is presented from left in Android and the menubar is still from left to right.
Any ideas?
New property link
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FlowDirection.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work out-of-the-box as expected on iOS but not on Android (extra actions required) with the next example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="RTL.MasterDetailPage"
    Padding="25"
    FlowDirection="RightToLeft">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title=" ">
            <StackLayout>
                <Button Text="Menu item" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage>
            <Label Text="My page"/>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Here is the outcome:
[image][image]

As you see on Android the menu appear on the left and on iOS on the right. <strike>Should check if there an existing bug report, if not should create a new one to the Xamarin.Forms team.</strike>

**Update:**
According to this [document](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1222) we have to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the application node in the manifest and ensure to set minSdk to 17+, without it won't work.
So here is the final outcome:

[image]

Comment: Thanks , also this is mentioned here but for the pre-release of Xamarin Forms 3
https://blog.xamarin.com/right-to-left-localization-xamarin-forms/

Comment: were you able to switch the locations of the icons in the navigation bar?
It looks wired having the menu appear from the right after clicking an icon from the left.